# How to change values of a column according to some conditions?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame named data1.

```
> data1 <- data.frame(name = c("apple","apple","pine","pine", 
                                 "apple","apple", "pine","pine","banana","banana"),
                        characters = c("red","green","yellow","brown",
                                       "big","sweet","delicious","medium","soft", "long"))

    > data1  
     name characters
1   apple        red
2   apple      green
3    pine     yellow
4    pine      brown
5   apple        big
6   apple      sweet
7    pine  delicious
8    pine     medium
9  banana       soft
10 banana       long
```

And I want to change the same values of the name variable according to the values of characters column.
Just like data2:

```
> data2
        name characters
1   colapple        red
2   colapple      green
3  colorpine     yellow
4  colorpine      brown
5   othapple        big
6   othapple      sweet
7    despine  delicious
8    despine     medium
9     banana       soft
10    banana       long
```

In fact, data1 is very big. And I need to change the same values in the data1$name into special values. So I need a general way to realize it. I try to use If statement to do it, but there are some errors. How can I do it?

Comment: I am not seeing the relation between the  columns, aren't the prefixes changing by groups of the 1st column?

Comment: There is the same value in the name variable, such as "apple". But the corresponding characters variable values are different.So I want to distinguish them.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the characters variable are different. Is the real input bigger, with always the same correspondence between `"characters"` and prefixes?

Comment: yes.I need to change the same values of data1$name according to the values of data3.

Comment: See the answer now after the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comment to the question, I am not seeing the relation between the columns, aren't the prefixes changing by groups of the 1st column?

If so, the code below will do what the question asks for. It creates an index `k` with a standard R `cumsum` trick. Then pastes the prefixes indexed by the index `k` and column `data1$name`.

```
pref <- c("col", "color", "oth", "des")
k <- cumsum(c(1, abs(diff(data1$name == "apple")) > 0))

data2 <- data.frame(name = paste0(pref[k], data1$name),
                    characters = data1$characters)

data2
#        name characters
#1   colapple        red
#2   colapple      green
#3   colapple      white
#4  colorpine     yellow
#5  colorpine      brown
#6  colorpine      black
#7   othapple        big
#8   othapple      sweet
#9   othapple      small
#10   despine  delicious
#11   despine     medium
#12   despine       ache
```

---

### Edit

With the new data set posted after the answer and following the discussion in comments, here is a solution with `setNames` and `match`.

```
pref3 <- c(rep("col", 2), rep("color", 2), rep("oth", 2), rep("des", 2), rep("", 2))
pref3 <- setNames(pref3, data3$characters)

k <- match(data3$characters, names(pref3))
data3$name <- paste0(pref3[k], data3$name)
```

---

### Data

```
data1 <- data.frame(name = c("apple","apple","apple", "pine","pine","pine",
                             "apple","apple","apple", "pine","pine","pine"),
                    characters = c("red","green","white","yellow","brown","black",
                                   "big","sweet","small","delicious","medium","ache"))

data3 <- data.frame(name = c("apple","apple","pine","pine", 
                             "apple","apple", "pine","pine","banana","banana"),
                    characters = c("red","green","yellow","brown",
                                   "big","sweet","delicious","medium","soft", "long"))
```